# How to prohibit a backslash with regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

I'm new with `regex` and just can't find what the regex is to prohibit a backslash.

Thanks for any advice.

EDIT:

I'm using the regex for JTextField, to avoid that the user writes an unvalid input. This `regex` currently doesnt allow the user to write a space character.

I'm doing this with

```
String regex = "\\S{1}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
```

So how I change my `regex` to prohibit backslash as well?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to do? Do you want to check if String contains ``\``? If so you don't have to even use regex. Or maybe you want to remove all ``\`` from String?

Comment: You mean a pattern that accepts anything except backslash? That would be: [^\\\]. If you want to convert the backslashes to backslash patterns in a pattern, use Pattern#quote().

Comment: Can we know why you even use regex here? It seems that simple `boolean isNotBackslash = !str.equals("\\");` would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example snippet, the following expression should work similarly, but also disallowing the backslash:

```
String regex = "[^\\s\\\\]{1}";
```

It is a bit strange that you are looking for a one-char non-space and non-backslash pattern, but I guess you are iterating through and checking for consecutive matches.

I would use the following regex though:

```
String regex = "[^\\s\\\\]+";
```

and check whether it matched the whole String (`matcher.matches()`).

Comment: Thanks, this works. Your previous hint with `"[^\\]"` for only baskslashes does not work, but `"[^\\\\]"` works.

Comment: That would also work, just it should be escaped as a String. :) If you were reading from a file, the [^\\\] would be the same as "[^\\\\\]" from code.

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern with java is `\\\\`

```
String somestring;
somestring = somestring.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Would remove them. Semantically it equates down to `\\` at the regex level, which becomes a literal `\` match.

You can also use a `Pattern` match if you want to just compare, or just use `String#contains`

```
String somestring;
if (somestring.contains("\\")) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

To *test* if a string has a backslash:

```
if (input.matches(".*\\\\.*"))
```

To *remove* backslashes from strings:

```
input = input.replace("\\", "");
```

Note the use of the non-regex based `replace()` method.